# How to conditionally exit an imported module in Python, so that code execution continues in the caller (or master) script

Tags: python

I have tried using sys.exit() within the relevant if...else condition in the imported module (let's call this 'test.py'), but this seems to cause Python to also immediately exit the caller script ('master.py').
As there is still a lot of code to be executed in 'master.py' after the code line:
import test
I was just wondering if there is an optimal way to achieve my goal above?
Please note that I have looked at Python documentation for such functions as exit() and quit(), and I think they will not help me either... But please do correct me if otherwise.
Thank you.

Comment: This is very unclear, what do you mean "exit imported module" ? Please explain more what is the final objective, you only talk about what you did. Maybe share python code could help

Comment: Objective is for the main code file, master.py, to execute some code, then call script test.py (via 'import test') so that the code in file test.py executes (either in full - which is 90% of the time - or in part, conditional on the relevant if---else criteria highlighted in the original post), before control MUST be returned to the main master.py script file, so that execution of the remaining code in this master.py script can occur to completion. Hope this clarifies... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just answered ;)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you misunderstand the use and goals of imports, the code `import test` is NOT to execute `test.py` but rather load methods from it, to be used later, that allows, in your case, to choose the part to run

If you have code that executes automatically in a file that you load, you need to be careful and ensure that codes really need to be called automatically  each time

---

#### Wrong use

```
""" test.py """

for i in range(10):
    print(i)

for j in range(20):
    print(j)

""" main.py """

import test
```

#### Good use

```
""" test.py """

def fct_a():
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)   

def fct_b():
    for j in range(20):
        print(j)


""" main.py """

import test

test.fct_a()

# test.fct_b() # don't call if you don't want to
```